# How I ended up deleting all records that not specified in query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am really intrigued how I ended up deleting records with this query including

```
CREATE temporary TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp AS 
  (SELECT colleges.college_name, 
          courses.course_name 
   FROM   colleges 
          INNER JOIN courses 
                  ON colleges.id = courses.college_id 
   WHERE  colleges.college_name = 'College of Engineering' 
          AND courses.course_name = 'test' 
   GROUP  BY colleges.college_name, 
             courses.course_name); 

DELETE FROM temp 
WHERE  college_name = 'College of Engineering' 
       AND course_name = 'test'; 

DROP TABLE temp;
```

Table colleges have the values 'College of Engineering' and 'College of Communication' while table courses have the both values 'test'. The result of the query was both test values was deleted instead of test in College of Engineering.

Comment: You noticed the missing `'` ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't noticed it. Edited

Answer (score 2):

The query that creates the temp table is filtered to `colleges.COLLEGE_NAME = 'College of Engineering'` so it will only contain rows with that value. The `DELETE` statement uses the exact same filtering so it is going to delete all of the rows in the temp table.